# How can I avoid that in-line icons jump to the next line in mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]
How can I avoid that the icon jumps to the next line?

In desktop the icons are in-line but in mobile I can't make the icons fit horizontally the screen.

This is the code of the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light bg-company-dark nav2" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <div class="d-flex container justify-content-end">
        <button class="iconButton" onclick="window.location.href='/';"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        <button id="translateFromApps" class="iconButton">
            <i class="fas fa-language"></i>
        </button>
        <button id="deleteApp" class="iconButton"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
        <button id="toggleApp" class="iconButton"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
        <a class="iconButton" href="apps/createApp"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
        <button id="editApp" class="iconButton"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: do you have another css?? https://jsfiddle.net/dp7fcw8j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `flex-warp:wrap`  in the class `.navbar>.container, .navbar>.container-fluid{}` makes the button jump into the next line ...you can either remove it or reduce the padding to fit the buttons in the container

The CSS flex-wrap property specifies whether flex items are forced into a single line or can be wrapped onto multiple lines. If wrapping is allowed, this property also enables you to control the direction in which lines are stacked.

Comment: Adding flex wrap avoided the jump to next line, then with some padding and margin I could centered it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following css and you're done...

```
.navbar>.container>* {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 35px;
}
.d-flex.container.justify-content-end>*>* {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```